# Как связать JavaScript и python в рамках плагина Chrome для парсинга?

Tags: javascript, python, парсер

Возникла задача написать парсер для сайта с криптой. Заказчик попросил отсылать push-уведомления при изменениях на сайте. Говорит, что скорость имеет первоочередное значение. Подскажите, возможно ли активировать python скрипт в такой ситуации или стоит поступить как то иначе? Просто плагины для Хрома работают через Js, а я работаю только на python

Comment: Вы можете на js проверять обновление и если оно произошло, отправлять бэку на python уведомление и уже на python реализовывать всю нужную логику. Однако полностью обойтись без js не получится

Comment: И да, и нет. Есть wasm, но пока будешь разбираться, что к чему и как, проще уже на JS научиться писать. При чём с трудом верится, что python быстрее js работать будет

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, тут у вас может быть классическая проблема [XY](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_XY_(%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0)#:%7E:text=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%20XY%20%E2%80%94%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%2C%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8F,%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83%20X.).
Вам нужны данные в push уведомлении или именно парсер для сайта?

Какого рода данные? Может, вы можете обойтись данными напрямую из API? Или, даже, подключиться к сокет соединению интересующего сайта напрямую из Phyton апки?
Исследуйте API.

В случае, если вы хотите долго городить сложный и ненадежный инструмент, то можете сделать это в 3 этапа:

1. Какой-нибудь [puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/) может из Phyton апки подключаться к сайту
2. далее, ставить в puppeteer [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) и подключать сокет соединение с вашим Phyton приложением. Как только MutationObserver ловит изменение, то JS может проверять изменение, и, если оно релевантно, пушить в сокет
3. Phyton апка ловит сокет ивент и пушит требовательному клиенту

**Итого**:

- Исследуйте API, может вам не нужен парсер потому, что его делать долго и сложно. Может, эти же данные есть в другом месте. Например, нет смысла парсить бинанс за real-time курсом битка. Есть бесконечное кол-во сервисов, которые предоставляют нужные данные. Например, `api.coincap.io`.
- Если с API не выходит, то попробуйте сделать парсер, но дело мутное и с большими рисками.